# Why an I getting "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView _isResizable]: unrecognized selector"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, unrecognized-selector

http://pt-br.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=300rxip&s=8#.VDhDStTF8mc

My UIImageView is connected to a TableViewCell as you can see above (my reputation is too low to post images, so I had to upload it on tinypic).

The cell code for this image is here:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ExtratoDeNotasSideMenuTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

@end
```

After that I specify which image it receives:

```
- (ExtratoDeNotasSideMenuTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ExtratoDeNotasSideMenuTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ExtratoDeNotasSideMenuTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icone_SideBar.png"];
    cell.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.menuItens objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

But it doesn't work, the message:
 "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa81356da40'" keeps showing.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: how does your cell connect to the properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[UITableViewCell image]` is a deprecated selector that is expected by the system to be a `UIImage`. You have overridden this name and returned a `UIImageView` instead, making the internal source that's expecting a `UIImage` fail.

Solution: rename your `image` property.

Comment: I renamed my "image" property to cellImage, reconnected the property to the imageview and now there's another problem, I'm getting:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ExtratoDeNotasMainMenuTableViewCell 0x7fad08634250> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key cellImage.'
Now I'm even more confused.

Comment: Can you update your source above to show your changes? It might make things clearer.